# Disallowed Key Characters - MX Google Maps extension

Tags: mx-google-map

Using EE 2.8.1 I get 'Disallowed Key Characters' after setting up the field type.
I have downloaded the latest MX Google Maps extension.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what happens? you setup field type and after that you get 'Disallowed Key Characters'?  In this case - what is your field name? What parameters you choose? Or you get error when you save new entry in channel with MX Google Map?

Comment: It happens after I Create a New Channel Field with MX Google field type. I named it location

Comment: Bump: In fact with the fieldtype installed and enabled I get the error when choosing other field type.

Comment: is this site online? can I looks inside? I tested last version with 2.9 and it works fine, so I need to see at least what data is posted at the moment of form submit. Or you can send me this info - open in Chrome inspector - > Network -> click on link and copy info from Headers. send to max at eec.ms

Answer (score 0):

I had this error error few times but not with this field type (i'm not using it). The problem occurred when the mod_security was ON on a shared hosting... Maybe you can check that!